# Did not want coworkers to know about death of parent

Tags: death, family

I recently lost my Mom unexpectedly.

I asked my manager, who is also HR, not to tell anyone. She told me that she would only tell the owners but no one else. I got back to work after taking some time off, and it turns out that she emailed the entire company, completely going against my wishes and even told the mailman. This was not her information to share and I now feel not only violated, and that I can no longer trust her.

She has made this loss so much harder on me than it needed to be. To make it worse, she recently lost a loved one (prior to my Mom's passing) and asked me not to tell anyone and I did not.

I am also angry at her for not reciprocating and honoring my wishes. I am not sure how to handle this situation.

I don't have the energy to look for a new job with all that I am dealing with but am always angry at my current one.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see what is your actual question. They already know, no way to un-know things, so that's not it... What question could people here answer for you to help?

Comment: Sorry to hear that... what is your question that you would like us to help you with?

Comment: Very sorry to hear what you have gone through but on this board this question could be seen as being 'too broad' or 'unclear what you're asking'.  It may end up having the question closed.  Please see https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and do not take it personally if you're question is closed.  On another note I sympathise with your dillemma but what is done is done and you just need to look after yourself first and go from there.  Work is not everything.

Answer (score 6):

I'm very sorry for your loss. Anything you share with your manager is private (there are some exceptions e.g. threatening to harm yourself or coworkers) and should not be shared broadly, especially, because you specifically stated you did not want your loss shared.

I understand how you feel. My former manager shared with others at my company that my wife and I were going through IVF. I'm not ashamed of our infertility struggles, but it's my information and I would like to be the one to share the information should I chose to.

I think your grief makes this betrayal of confidence more difficult to handle. I would like to think that your manager had good intentions sharing the news of your loss with the company so that everyone would give you the space you needed to grieve. Whether that's exactly what happened is a mystery that's not important to solve now. It's better to focus on how to move on your life having lost your mother right now. Later when things have settled, talk to your manager about how her actions made you feel and go from there.

Comment: I would call that manager “pig-ignorant” for completely ignoring what she was asked to do - especially as she had asked for, and received, the self-same consideration...

Answer (score 5):

First, I am sorry for your loss. I wish that you will manage to get though these difficult times as "easy" as possible.

Regarding your boss, she did the most non-professional thing she could do. Even without your request, and without any history of anything, she had to keep your secret. Confidentiality of personal information is mandatory by many laws worldwide. And one's family is very VERY personal information.

Regarding a "solution", the most beneficial thing to do is to "pretend" that everything is OK. You cannot remove information from the people's minds. You cannot go back in time to change anything. **Searching for a new job is NOT a good idea** in your current condition - you are already going through a lot (loss, boss, colleagues, job...), you will (most probably) make significant mistakes in the process - which you will come to regret.

For a while, **just let time to do its thing**. When your mind and feelings begin to get clearer, that is the moment to start thinking about what to do. It can take anywhere from a few days to several weeks - there is no exact science about this.

It is also quite clear that your boss cannot be trusted with anything from now on. Except job-related stuff, do not share with her any sensitive information.